# AngularJS IE11 Invalid Argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

This issue is driving me crazy... I remove all $http calls, and all textboxs/textarea.

I don't know what else to check. For some reason i think it has to do with nested pages in ui-Router. I only get this error(actually 14 times in a row) on nested pages.

I also add the attribute about placeholder (ng-attr-placeholder) and i am still getting the error.

Any suggestions would be great.

```
Error: Invalid argument.
   at interpolateFnWatchAction (http://localhost:16266/Scripts/app/vendors/angularjs/angular.js:6834:15)
   at Scope.prototype.$digest (http://localhost:16266/Scripts/app/vendors/angularjs/angular.js:12251:23)
   at Scope.prototype.$apply (http://localhost:16266/Scripts/app/vendors/angularjs/angular.js:12516:13)
   at done (http://localhost:16266/Scripts/app/vendors/angularjs/angular.js:8204:34)
   at completeRequest (http://localhost:16266/Scripts/app/vendors/angularjs/angular.js:8412:7)
   at xhr.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:16266/Scripts/app/vendors/angularjs/angular.js:8351:11)
```

State Config

```
//-----------HOME--------------------------------
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/requests',
                    templateUrl: mySettings.root + 'Scripts/App/js/views/home.html',
                    controller: 'homeController',
                    data: { pageTitle: 'Dashboard' }
                }) //---------Create New Order-----------------------
                .state('home.create', {
                    url: '/create',
                    templateUrl: mySettings.root + 'Scripts/App/js/views/create.html',
                    resolve: {
                        isReOrder: [
                            function() {
                                return false;
                            }
                        ],
                        requestData: [
                            function() {
                                return null;
                            }
                        ],
                        vendorsData: [
                            'addressesService', function(addressesService) {
                                return addressesService.query({ type: 'vendor' }).$promise;
                            }
                        ],
                        unitOfMeasureData: [
                            'loopUpOptionsService', function (loopUpOptionsService) {
                                return loopUpOptionsService.query({ lookupid: 'UnitOfMeasure', active: true }).$promise;
                            }
                        ],
                        addressesData: [
                            'officeManagers', 'authService', function (officeManagers, authService) {
                                return officeManagers.getAddressesByUsername({ id: authService.authentication.userName }).$promise;
                                   }
                        ],
                        locationsData: [
                            'locations', function(locations) {
                                 return locations.query().$promise; 
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    controller: 'createController',
                    data: { pageTitle: 'Create Order' }
                })
```

Thanks.

Comment: the reference to `xhr.onreadystatechange` does make this appear to be an issue with ui-router, but some code is really necessary to diagnose anything at all.

Comment: @Claies I added some of state config when i go to \requests\create i get the error 14 times

Comment: ok, so you have a series of resolves there; any of those could throw the error, and the controller is not instantiated until all resolve objects return a value.

Comment: @Claies I removed the series of resolves and i still having the issue.

Comment: hmm, then the issue is in the controller or the html template

Comment: blank controller and blank html template and still getting the error errrr

Comment: only when going to this route?

Comment: all nested routes: home.create,home.requestId.details, home.requestId.save, home.requestId.reorder. admin.userid.detail .. etc so basically i don't get the error on home, admin, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally figure out the issue. It has to do with the home.html (parent state), when i go to the child page (home.create), it try to render the parent page... not sure why... i think it is because parent and child have different controller/data.

To fix it i had to add this on the home template inside the ui-view where the data from the scope is render.

```
data-ng-if="$state.$current.name == 'home'"
```

so if the state is not home it doesn't try to render that section.

Thanks Claies for your help.